# Figuring out the size of the counter with a 50Mhz clock

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to generate a wave of 15 ms. My clock is 50Mhz. What I did is T = 1/(50MHz) then 15ms / 50Mhz. I found that I need 750K period, but I am not sure how to translate that to code.

My code so far:

```
process (CLK, RESET) 
  variable COUNT_WAVE: integer range 0 to 750001; -- counter for wave generation 

  begin 
    if (RESET = '1') then PRESS <= '0'; 
    elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then I_PRESS <= PRESS; 

    if (I_PRESS = '1') then 
      case COUNT_WAVE IS -- Generating wave of 15 ms -- 
        when 0 => NC <= '0' AND NO <= '1' ; 
        when 1 to 750000 => NC <= '1' AND NO <= '0'; 
        when 750001 => NC <= '0' AND NO <= '1' ; 
      end case; 

      COUNT_WAVE := COUNT_WAVE + 1; 
    end if;
```

Comment: You need to be more specific as to what type of "code" you are looking for and what you have tried.

Comment: I am writing in VHDL and I am trying to generate a wave form of 15ms when a botton is pressed:

Comment: process (CLK, RESET)
variable COUNT_WAVE    : integer range 0 to 750001; -- counter for wave generation 
begin
 if (RESET = '1') then
   PRESS <= '0';
 elsif clk'event and clk = '1' then
   I_PRESS <= PRESS; 
 if (I_PRESS = '1') then
 case COUNT_WAVE IS   -- Generating wave of 15 ms --
      when 0        => NC <= '0' AND NO <= '1' ;
      when 1 to 750000 => NC <= '1' AND NO <= '0';
      when 750001      => NC <= '0' AND NO <= '1' ;
      
     end case;
     COUNT_WAVE := COUNT_WAVE + 1;   
 end if;

Comment: apart from poor formatting and some basic syntax errors, this bit of the code looks reasonably OK. Was there a question?

Comment: As stated below a simulator might not allow you to have an overflow integer. The synth tool will make a vector of 20 bits. where your counter will wrap at 1048574. You'll need some reset logic to control your COUNT_WAVE

Answer (score 1):

My opinion on this is first, get rid of reset from the sensitivity list. This creates a asynchronous reset which is not good if you are considering metastability.

I would recommend this article https:http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2003Boston_Resets.pdf if you are interested in knowing more.

My philosophy is dont make code more complicated than it needs to be, it should be simple but not simpler.

Break out your process into separate sections. Each process should do only a specific task.

That will make the code easier to read.

example: have one process to do only counting, start counting only if enable is on etc

have another process to look at the count value, and generate a 1 or 0 based on that.

Comment: Removing the reset from the sensitivity list will not make it synchronous. The document you linked (nice one, btw.) recommends this method in section 4.1 for Verilog but not VHDL. In VHDL you put the reset logic inside the "if" that detects the raising clock edge. Another method is to synchronize it outside.

Comment: of course, however, removing it from the sensitivity list is the first step towards synchronous design

Comment: The sunburst paper is a good one, however .... could you please paste the bare URL without google :).

Answer (score 0):

I think your calculation is correct but the code has several problems.

1. The `COUNT_WAVE` variable is an integer with a range constraint. I don't think you are allowed to overflow those. At least Modelsim/Questa will complain loudly if you do, and I assume the synthesis tools will not build a comparator for you. I think you have to overflow *integer* (as opposed to *std_logic_vector* or *unsigned* which always have a power-of-two range) manually with an *if* statement.
2. It's bad practice to use variables to build registers. Anything that retains its state over clock cycles, e.g. `COUNT_WAVE`, should be a signal, not a variable.
3. The use of `PRESS` and `I_PRESS` seems confused. If they are registers or outputs, you should assign something to them both during reset and on on the rising edge. If they are inputs, you shouldn't assign anything at all.
4. `when 0 => NC <= '0' AND NO <= '1' ;` I have never seen this syntax, does that even compile? You probably want `;` instead of AND.

Comment: It is NOT bad practice to use variables to build registers. It's good practice to keep declarations as local as possible, and here a variable is declared closer to its use than a signal. Just be sure you are clear about the semantic differences between variable and signal assignments. As used here, there is no problem. Your other points are good.